# Graphing MIDI events in iOS using AudioKit

Tags: ios, audiokit

I want to create a graphical representation of a MIDI file. I am using AudioKit for my audio processing needs in my app.

I am loading the MIDI with an AKSequencer and using an AKMIDISampler to add a WAV file to the sequence.

Is there a way to do something like the view in GarageBand where you see the notes in a graphical representation using AudioKit?

The WAV part is not important for this. I jus want to be able to do draw the contents of the MIDI file.

Thanks!

Comment: I found a library which uses CoreAnimation to paint a Piano Roll. I myself am interested in such a view, maybe we can join development efforts?
https://github.com/mattrajca/MIDIVis

Comment: hello guys. i am going to work on similar stuff, read the note from midi file and build the sequencer graph. May i know how do u get the notes from midi file through audiokit? I tried to use AKSequencer and output to AKMIDINode to listen the MIDI event, but seems cannot get anything from it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988257/read-note-from-midi-file-using-audiokit

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are asking for is what is referred to as a Piano Roll in a typical DAW (like GarageBand).  AudioKit does not currently provide a built-in Piano Roll.  However, as AudioKit is open source, it could certainly be contributed sometime in the future.