# Read note from MIDI file using AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am trying to build a sequencer that render the note from midi file.

Currently I am using AudioKit for the music data processing. Would like to know how can I get the note data / event from the midi file with AudioKit.

I have tried to use AKSequencer and output to AKMIDINode to listen the MIDI event, but seems cannot get anything from it.

```
class CustomMIDINode: AKMIDINode {

    override init(node: AKPolyphonicNode) {
        print("Node create") // OK
        super.init(node: node)
    }

    func receivedMIDINoteOff(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        print("midi note off") // Not printed
    }

    func receivedMIDISetupChange() {
        print("midi setup changed") // Not printed
    }

    override func receivedMIDINoteOn(_ noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        print("receivedMIDINoteOn") // Not printed
    }
}

func setupSynth() {
    oscBank.attackDuration = 0.05
    oscBank.decayDuration = 0.1
    oscBank.sustainLevel = 0.1
    oscBank.releaseDuration = 0.1
}


let seq = AKSequencer(filename: "music")
let oscBank = AKOscillatorBank()
var midi = AKMIDI()
let midiNode = CustomMIDINode(node: oscBank)

setupSynth()

midi.openInput()
midi.addListener(midiNode)
seq.tracks.forEach { (track) in
    track.setMIDIOutput(midiNode.midiIn)
}
AudioKit.output = midiNode
AudioKit.start()
seq.play()
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at any of the example Audio Kit projects available for download? they are very useful for troubleshooting AK. I actually find the examples better than the documentation (as implementation isn't explained very well).

As for your question you can add a midi listener to an event, there is an example of this code in the [Analog Synth X](http://audiokit.io/examples/AnalogSynthX/) Project [available here](http://audiokit.io/downloads/).

```
let midi = AKMIDI()
        midi.createVirtualPorts()
        midi.openInput("Session 1")
        midi.addListener(self)
```

For a more worked bit of code you can [refer to this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/audiokit/RAL9oKHnX_c) although the code is likely out of date in parts.

Answer (score 1):

Tony, is it that you aren’t receiving any MIDI events, or just the print statements?

I agree with Axemasta’s response about adding `AKMidiListener` to the class, along with checking out the MIDI code examples that come with AudioKit. This ROM Player example shows how to play external MIDI files with the `AKMidiSsmpler` node:

https://github.com/AudioKit/ROMPlayer

In order for the print to display, try wrapping it in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` so that it’s on the main thread. Here’s an AudioKit MIDI implementation question with a code example that I posted here:

[AudioKit iOS - receivedMIDINoteOn function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302292/audiokit-ios-receivedmidinoteon-function)

I hope this helps.