# AudioKit iOS - receivedMIDINoteOn function

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

I'm trying to use the receivedMIDINoteOn function to flash a UILabel when the sequencer is playing a note. I have tried using the AKMIDIListener protocol with no success. Also I have made a sub class of AKMIDISampler and send midi to it from the sequencer. It plays the midi but the receivedMIDINoteOn is not called.

This is what I have in the init() of the conductor:

```
init() {

    [ahSampler, beeSampler, gooSampler,flasher] >>> samplerMixer
    AudioKit.output = samplerMixer
    AudioKit.start()



    let midi = AKMIDI()
    midi.createVirtualPorts()
    midi.openInput("Session 1")
    midi.addListener(self)
}
```

The conductor follows AKMIDIListener protocol

this is the function: it is never called

```
func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel)
{
    print("got it")
}
```

And this is the sub class of AKMIDISampler, it gets midi and plays the sine synth, but the receivedMIDINoteOn is never called.

```
class Flasher: AKMIDISampler
{
    override func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity:    MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel)
    {
        print("Flasher got it!")
    }
}
```

edit: I should have been using the AKCallbackInstrument class instead, and overriding it's start() function.

Answer (score 5):

Ben,

Without seeing your entire project, I would guess that if your project is able to receive and trigger MIDI notes, then it's an issue with only sending its output to the UILabel. I recommend using NotificationCenter to inform the ViewController when a MIDI event has been received in the `Conductor` class. Be sure to add the `DispatchQueue.main.async` code, or else the text won't update as expected. This was noted in the AudioKit Google Group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/audiokit/tnC5YWeYWnw).

**Example:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        nc.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "outputMessage"),
                object: nil,
                userInfo: [
                    "message": self.outputMIDIMessage,
                    "midiSignalReceived": self.midiSignalReceived,
                    "midiTypeReceived": self.midiTypeReceived
        ])
})
```

I would also recommend the following:

Move `let midi = AKMIDI()` into an instance variable outside of the `init()` at the top of your Conductor class, rather than inside of it. It looks like you're attempting to create it after `AudioKit.start()`.

I posted a sample project that demonstrates how you can change a UILabel's color whenever a MIDI note number has been received via AudioKit:

https://github.com/markjeschke/AKMidiReceiver

**Conductor class:**

```
import AudioKit

enum MidiEventType: String {
    case
        noteNumber          = "Note Number",
        continuousControl   = "Continuous Control",
        programChange       = "Program Change"
}

class Conductor: AKMIDIListener {

    // Globally accessible
    static let sharedInstance = Conductor()

    // Set the instance variables outside of the init()
    let midi = AKMIDI()

    var demoSampler = SamplerAudioFileLoader()
    var samplerMixer = AKMixer()
    var outputMIDIMessage = ""
    var midiSignalReceived = false
    var midiTypeReceived: MidiEventType = .noteNumber

    init() {

        // Session settings
        AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium
        AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true

        // Allow audio to play while the iOS device is muted.
        AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true

        do {
            try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .mixWithOthers])
        } catch {
            AKLog("Could not set session category.")
        }

        // File path options are:
        // "TX Brass"
        // "TX LoTine81z"
        // "TX Metalimba"
        // "TX Pluck Bass"
        demoSampler.loadEXS24Sample(filePath: "TX Brass")

        // If you wish to load a wav file, comment the `loadEXS24` method and uncomment this one:
//      demoSampler.loadWavSample(filePath: "Kick") // Load Kick wav file

        [demoSampler] >>> samplerMixer
        AudioKit.output = samplerMixer
        AudioKit.start()

        // MIDI Configure
        midi.createVirtualInputPort(98909, name: "AKMidiReceiver")
        midi.createVirtualOutputPort(97789, name: "AKMidiReceiver")
        midi.openInput()
        midi.openOutput()
        midi.addListener(self)

    }

    // Capture the MIDI Text within a DispatchQueue, so that it's on the main thread.
    // Otherwise, it won't display.
    func captureMIDIText() {
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            nc.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "outputMessage"),
                    object: nil,
                    userInfo: [
                        "message": self.outputMIDIMessage,
                        "midiSignalReceived": self.midiSignalReceived,
                        "midiTypeReceived": self.midiTypeReceived
                ])
        })
    }

    // MARK: MIDI received

    // Note On Number + Velocity + MIDI Channel
    func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        midiTypeReceived = .noteNumber
        outputMIDIMessage = "\(midiTypeReceived.rawValue)\nChannel: \(channel+1)  noteOn: \(noteNumber)  velocity: \(velocity)"
        print(outputMIDIMessage)
        midiSignalReceived = true
        captureMIDIText()
        playNote(note: noteNumber, velocity: velocity, channel: channel)
    }

    // Note Off Number + Velocity + MIDI Channel
    func receivedMIDINoteOff(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        midiTypeReceived = .noteNumber
        outputMIDIMessage = "\(midiTypeReceived.rawValue)\nChannel: \(channel+1)  noteOff: \(noteNumber)  velocity: \(velocity)"
        print(outputMIDIMessage)
        midiSignalReceived = false
        captureMIDIText()
        stopNote(note: noteNumber, channel: channel)
    }

    // Controller Number + Value + MIDI Channel
    func receivedMIDIController(_ controller: MIDIByte, value: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        // If the controller value reaches 127 or above, then trigger the `demoSampler` note.
        // If the controller value is less, then stop the note.
        // This creates an on/off type of "momentary" MIDI messaging.
        if value >= 127 {
            playNote(note: 30 + controller, velocity: 80, channel: channel)
        } else {
            stopNote(note: 30 + controller, channel: channel)
        }
        midiTypeReceived = .continuousControl
        outputMIDIMessage = "\(midiTypeReceived.rawValue)\nChannel: \(channel+1)  controller: \(controller)  value: \(value)"
        midiSignalReceived = true
        captureMIDIText()
    }

    // Program Change Number + MIDI Channel
    func receivedMIDIProgramChange(_ program: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        // Trigger the `demoSampler` note and release it after half a second (0.5), since program changes don't have a note off release.
        triggerSamplerNote(program, channel: channel)
        midiTypeReceived = .programChange
        outputMIDIMessage = "\(midiTypeReceived.rawValue)\nChannel: \(channel+1)  programChange: \(program)"
        midiSignalReceived = true
        captureMIDIText()
    }

    func receivedMIDISetupChange() {
        print("midi setup change")
        print("midi.inputNames: \(midi.inputNames)")

        let listInputNames = midi.inputNames

        for inputNames in listInputNames {
            print("inputNames: \(inputNames)")
            midi.openInput(inputNames)
        }
    }

    func playNote(note: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        demoSampler.play(noteNumber: note, velocity: velocity, channel: channel)
    }

    func stopNote(note: MIDINoteNumber, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        demoSampler.stop(noteNumber: note, channel: channel)
    }

    func triggerSamplerNote(_ program: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel) {
        playNote(note: 60 + program, velocity: 80, channel: channel)
        let releaseNoteDelay = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5 // Change 0.5 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: releaseNoteDelay) {
            self.stopNote(note: 60 + program, channel: channel)
            self.midiSignalReceived = false
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewController with the UILabel:**

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputTextLabel: UILabel!

    var conductor = Conductor.sharedInstance
    var midiSignalReceived = false
    var midiTypeReceived: MidiEventType = .noteNumber

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        nc.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "outputMessage"), object:nil, queue:nil, using:catchNotification)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        flashBackgroundColor()
        midiSignalReceived = false
        self.outputTextLabel.text = "Listening for MIDI events..."
    }

    @objc func catchNotification(notification:Notification) -> Void {
        guard
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let message  = userInfo["message"] as? String,
            let midiSignalReceived = userInfo["midiSignalReceived"] as? Bool,
            let midiTypeReceived = userInfo["midiTypeReceived"] as? MidiEventType else {
                print("No userInfo found in notification")
                return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.outputTextLabel.text = message
            self.midiSignalReceived = midiSignalReceived
            self.midiTypeReceived = midiTypeReceived
            self.flashBackgroundColor()
        })
    }

    @objc func flashBackgroundColor() {
        if midiSignalReceived {
            self.outputTextLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            if midiTypeReceived != .noteNumber {
                self.perform(#selector(dismissFlashBackgroundColor), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
            }
        } else {
            dismissFlashBackgroundColor()
        }
    }

    @objc func dismissFlashBackgroundColor() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.outputTextLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.midiSignalReceived = false
            self.conductor.midiSignalReceived = false
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "outputMessage"),
                                                  object: nil)
    }

}
```

**SamplerAudioFileLoader.swift:**

```
import AudioKit

class SamplerAudioFileLoader: AKMIDISampler {

    internal func loadWavSample(filePath: String) {
        do {
            try self.loadWav("Sounds/\(filePath)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not locate the Wav file.")
        }
    }

    internal func loadEXS24Sample(filePath: String) {
        do {
            try self.loadEXS24("Sounds/Sampler Instruments/\(filePath)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not locate the EXS24 file.")
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any questions about this.

Take care,

Mark

P.S. If you clone this [AKMidiReceiver example](https://github.com/markjeschke/AKMidiReceiver), open the Workspace, and no scheme appears in the Xcode project, please follow these steps that were found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755799/xcode-no-scheme):

1. Click on No Scheme
2. Click on Manage Scheme
3. Click on Autocreate Schemes Now

Comment: Your project is helpful in so many way! So first of all thanks for sharing it.     I'm actually trying to do something different: I want to use the midi output of an AKSequencer to flash the UILabel, so there is no midi input from an external devise involved. I've implemented a sequencer in your project and noticed that even though the sampler is playing the receivedMIDINoteOn function is not called, so I guess maybe I'm in the wrong direction. Do you know if the receivedMIDINoteOn function could be called when the midi is coming from a sequencer? And if not, what else could I do?

Comment: Apparently I was going in the wrong direction, should have been using the AKCallbackInstrument instead. And thanx for the DispatchQueue.main.async tip! It did come handy at the end, now I got flashing alright :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and that you were able to solve flashing indicator via the AKCallbackInstrument. I would love to see your sequencer in action, if and when it becomes public.

Comment: Sure thing. I’d love to.

Comment: @BenSpector, I updated this GitHub example with Xcode 11.2.1 and AudioKit 4.9.2: https://github.com/markjeschke/AKMidiReceiver

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @mark, at the moment I have some local [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521803/audiokit-akmidiinstrument-crashes-on-init-after-upgrading-to-xcode-11) preventing me from running the latest AudioKit, will be solved soon hopefully so I can run your project.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you initialize flasher, you may have to run flasher.enableMIDI() optionally with names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added **flasher.enableMIDI()** line after **AudioKit.start()** but no change. not sure how to use the one with names, could really use some help there. also how can I get the AKMIDIListener to call  receivedMIDINoteOn function? thank you so much.

Comment: BTW, flasher **is** playing the midi that I send it, it just does not call the override function receivedMIDINoteOn.